# Проблема с обращением к массиву внутри функции из класса

Tags: php, массивы, ооп

Нужно обратится к массиву, который находится внутри функции, а функция в свою очередь внутри класса.
Инициализацию класса я сделал, IDE ошибок не выдаёт.

Код должен выводить данные из массива (Версию то-есть, (1.0)) на экран, но почему-то этого не происходит.

Сам код:

```
<?php

class Will__Application
{
   function info()
   {
      $array = array
      (
         "version" => "1.0"
      );
   }
}

$Will__Application = new Will__Application();

echo $Will__Application->info()->$array['version'];

?>
```

Comment: Метод info ничего не возвращает.

Comment: @u_mulder, честно говоря я даже не представляю какое значение должна возвращать данная функция. Ваш ответ я обдумал хорошо, но не к какому решению задачи не пришёл. Извиняюсь за скудность знаний. Перебрал значение - true, false, $array, но ничего не помогло. Для справки версия php 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
class Will__Application
{
   function info()
   {
      $array = array
      (
         "version" => "1.0"
      );

      return $array;
   }
}


$Will__Application = new Will__Application();

echo $Will__Application->info()['version'];
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли